# necessity and sufficiency condition on being an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

$f:U \rightarrow V $- linear map,
   $U,V  $ - Euclidean spaces.

I need to show, that
$ [ \  \forall_{u\in  U}:||f(u)|| = ||u|| \ ] \Rightarrow [ \ \forall_{u,v \in U} \ f(u) \cdot f(v) = u \cdot v \ ]$

I have problem with understanding the prove. This is how it goes:

$ f(v) \cdot f(u) = $ (this is my problem) $  = \frac{1}{2} ( ||f(u)+f(v)||^2 - ||f(u)||^2 - ||f(v)||^2 )$
$ = \frac{1}{2} ( ||u+v||^2 - ||u||^2 - ||v||^2 ) =$ (again I don't know why) $ = u \cdot v$

Is it true, that $f(u) \cdot f(v) = ||f(u)|| \ ||f(v)||$ ?

Comment: You should use `\cdot` for inner product. `\circ` is for function composition.

Comment: What's $\|a+b\|^2$? It's precisely $(a+b)\cdot(a+b)$, by definition. So $\|a+b\|^2=a\cdot a + 2 a\cdot b + b\cdot b$. And that's exactly $\|a\|^2 + 2 a\cdot b + \| b\|^2$, so $a\cdot b = \frac{1}{2} (\|a+b\|^2 - \|a\|^2 - \|b\|^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rembember the definition of $\|w\|^2$, i.e. $$\|w\|^2=w\cdot w$$